# Get ProjectServer Installed version using PSI

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-project-server-2013

How do I get the version of the currently installed Project Server in C# using PSI (ProjectServer Interface)?

I looked around the ProjectServer (bad) api documentation and couldn't find a property or method that returns the version.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any such functionality. But you can always create your PSI extension which will return required data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ReadServerVersion method from the Admin Web Service for that.
For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcadmin.admin.readserverversion_di_pj14mref(v=office.15).aspx